# Unable to save merged articles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I'm trying to create a feature for Typo (blogging app) that merges two articles in one. For some reason, I can't manage to save the merged article. I have followed several threads here, read over and over Rails and Ruby docs... And Can't figure out why it doesn't work

Besides finding what's wrong with my code, I'd like to know best solutions to see what's going on 'under the hood', to debug the code. Eg: See when methods are called, what parameters are passed...

Here is my code:

View:

```
<% if @article.id && @user_is_admin %>
    <h4>Merge Articles</h4>
    <%=form_tag :action => 'merge_with', :id => @article.id do %>
        <%= label_tag 'merge_with', 'Article ID' %>
        <%= text_field_tag 'merge_with' %>
        <%= submit_tag 'Merge' %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

Controller

```
def merge_with 
    unless Profile.find(current_user.profile_id).label == "admin"
      flash[:error] = _("You are not allowed to perform a merge action")
      redirect_to :action => index
    end
    article = Article.find_by_id(params[:id])
    debugger
    if article.merge_with(params[:merge_with])
      flash[:notice] = _("Articles successfully merged!")
      redirect_to :action => :index
    else
      flash[:notice] = _("Articles couldn't be merged")
      redirect_to :action => :edit, :id => params[:id]
    end
  end
```

Model:

```
def merge_with(other_article_id)
    other_article = Article.find_by_id(other_article_id)
    if not self.id or not other_article.id
      return false
    end
    self.body = self.body + other_article.body
    self.comments << other_article.comments
    self.save!
    other_article = Article.find_by_id(other_article_id)
    other_article.destroy
  end
```

Thanks in advance, and sorry if this is a rookie question :)

Comment: You need to add some console output to see what the error is. I don't usually use anything to debug my code as the Rails.console is more than enough.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mentioned what problem you are facing while saving, you just said you could not manage to save so I can't help you with that unless you provide some stack trace.
I will mention a few things though:

first is in your controller method you have multiple redirection code like `redirect_to :action => index` without any `return` from method so I think you will get `multiple redirect or render` error at some point like when `unless` executes and redirects but code continues the execution and throws error so try to reduce these redirects or mention it like `redirect_to :action => index and return`.

Then in model `merge_with` you are assigning `other_article` twice, you don't need the second one.

about debugging, you can create some `puts` line inside code and check it in rails server console to verify that the condition is executed like in controller method after `if article.merge_with` you can put:

```
puts "merge sucess"
```

and check console when merge action is called, if you see `"merge sucess"` then `if` block executed.

OR
use `byebug` like you used `debugger`. It will stop the execution where it will find the `byebug` word and will give access to a live session in rails console.
if you put it where you have `debugger` you can access the console and do the operations manually like run:

```
article.merge_with(params[:merge_with])
```

then see what happens. or put before `self.save!` in model and save it manually in console and check errors like `self.errors.messages`.

Stack trace is also helpful to see line by line code execution and identify the error.

I will update this if you post any info about what error you are facing

Comment: I don't get any error, code runs, I merge articles, get the flash success... But then the articles are not merge into a new one, nor deleted the previous one.

Comment: Then try putting a `byebug` line above `self.save!` in your model and check the elements. like what does the `self.body` have at that point.

Comment: I don't get any error, when I try to use the feature I see the form to merge articles, I add the article id, press merge, get redirected to index with flash success... But nothing happens. No merged article is created and old articles aren't deleted.

Thanks for the trick 'puts ..', very clever to see if it gets executed. I can't use byebug because is Ruby 1.9.3. Where do I see the stack trace? 

Thanks

Comment: stack trace is shown in console if any error raises so you can't see in this case . And since you can't use byebug, try `puts self.body` after `self.body = self.body + other_article.body`

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I will try to figure it out, now I'm officially stuck